# How to get params form route pass to multi component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

code is :
in course component have other component how to pass params on it ?
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
component: HomeComponent
},
{
path: ':courseUrl',
component: CourseComponent,
}
]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: read that first, then improve your question for the next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `constructor` at `course-component.ts` u could subscribe to query parameters like this

```
constructor(
    ...
    /* your other codes*/
    ...
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
){
    ...
    /* your other codes*/
    ...
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
         console.log(params);
    });
}
```

u will see `courseUrl` at your console, change `console.log(params)` to something like `this.courseUrlParam = params` to store that `params` to a variable